# Diferenças no momento de instanciar uma classe

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes, instanciar-objeto

Utilizando o `PHP` ao instanciar um objeto eu o faço da seguinte forma:

```php
$obj = NEW my_class_exemplo;
```

porém sempre o auto complete do netbeans me da a opção de colocar com parenteses assim:

```php
$obj = NEW my_class_exemplo();
```

**Pergunta:** Existe alguma diferença na utilização de alguma das opções em termos de performance e mecânica?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Na prática, não parece existir nenhuma diferença.*

Pelo que percebo, a maioria das pessoas e das implementações de IDE preferem instanciar com parêntesis para seguir o *code standard* usado na própria documentação do PHP e pela comunidade em geral, que segue o de outras linguagens orientadas a objetos.

Não encontrei uma referência na documentação do PHP, apenas uma na [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_syntax_and_semantics) que diz:

> Chamadas a funções devem ter um parêntesis, com exceção da função do construtor de classes quando esta não tem argumentos e é chamado com o operador `new` do PHP, onde os parêntesis são opcionais *(tradução livre)*.

Alguém pode argumentar que economizando os dois caracteres (2 bytes se usar a codificação ASCII, 4 se for um UTF-8, ...) seu arquivo PHP seria carregado e interpretado mais rapidamente. No entanto, qualquer ganho provavelmente será insignificante e não mensurável, já que arquivos PHP são sempre cheios de caracteres "sobrando", principalmente quando misturados com HTML.

Answer (score 5):

Na realidade o uso ou não do parênteses é opcional quando você não informa dados ao construtor da classe.
A real necessidade de informar os parênteses é de repassar dados ao construtor.
Mas por questão de padronização sempre utilize com parênteses, como dito pra manter um padrão.

```
<?php

class Foo {

    public function __construct() {
    }
}

class Bar {

    public function __construct( $data ) {

    }
}

new Foo; # Instancia correta, não acusará erro.
new Bar; # Instancia errada, acusará erro.
```